Measured value represents range in timeseries
I have datasets that consist of measured points (measuring m), across a landscape/area (x and y) and time (t). The issue comes in that the measurements are actually made over a period of time, a month for example. At the end of the month, the samplers are analysed and we receive a single measurement value for that time period. Currently, we take the mid-point of the period when the samplers were out measuring or, average up to that measurement being representative of a whole month. The attached image hopefully also helps to explain. the lines are plotted through the mid-points while the points (so close they look like horizontal lines) show the full-range. The samplers measure at a constant rate, so I think it's difficult to describe that pattern.
edit #1: The question is how can I suitably model these data, accouting for the fact that while I have a single value of m, it represent a timespan? I am keen to put together a statistical model to (hopefully) better understand patterns/differences between locations and months etc. and potentially predict forward/over space.
I feel like there might well be a better way of doing this - or maybe not. I've spent some time searching and using my previous knowledge but I'm currently out of ideas. In a perfect world, the method suggested would also be able to be adapted to include spatial information (x and y) and be run in R. Thanks in advance!

Dummy data used to make that plot (if useful):
set.seed(123)

series_A <- 50 + 10*sin(2*pi*time/12) + rnorm(12, 0, 5)
series_B <- 50 + 10*sin(2*pi*time/12 + pi/6) + rnorm(12, 0, 5)
series_C <- 50 + 10*sin(2*pi*time/12 + pi/3) + rnorm(12, 0, 5)

dates <- seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 12)

start_dates <- rep(dates, 3) + sample(c(0, 1, 3, 6, 10), 
                   length(dates), replace = TRUE)
end_dates <- start_dates + 14
mid_date <- start_dates
month <- lubridate::month(start_dates, label = TRUE)

mid_dates <- c()
for(i in 1:length(start_dates)){

  mid_dates <- c(mid_dates, seq(start_dates[i], end_dates[i], 
           by = 'days')[floor(length(seq(start_dates[i], end_dates[i], 
           by = 'days'))/2)])
    
}

data <- data.frame(start_time = start_dates,
                   end_dates = end_dates, 
                   mid_dates = as.Date(mid_dates),
                   month = month,
                   location = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 12),
                   measurement = c(series_A, series_B, series_C))

out <- list()

for(i in 1:length(start_dates)){

  pnt_dates <- seq(start_dates[i], end_dates[i], by = 'days')
  #out[[i]] <- data[rep(data[i,], each = length(pnt_dates)), ]  
  #out[[i]]$pnt_dates <- pnt_dates
  
  out[[i]] <- slice(data, rep(i, length(pnt_dates)))
  out[[i]]$pnt_dates <- pnt_dates
  
}

data2 <- do.call(rbind, out)

ggplot(data, aes(x = mid_dates, y = measurement, color = location, 
                 group = location)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = data2, aes(x = pnt_dates)) +
  labs(title = "Three Time Series with Seasonal Pattern",
       x = "Month",
       y = "Value",
       color = "Time Series")


Welcome to CV!  What is your question?  It seems to be about "doing this," but "this" might refer to all kinds of different aspects of your description ranging from how to sample to how to analyze the results to how to graph them.  Please clarify.

I'm so sorry, I somehow missed adding that. I've added it now. Thanks!
